# Find <img> in html string based on cid and replace with text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working in asp.net c#/VS2015.

I have a HTML string with some embedded images in it like:

```
string sHTML = "<table>
   <tr>
      <td><img src='cid:ii_15b82060d11f1e16' alt='Inline 1' width='538' height='404'></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><img src='cid:ii_15b761fdbaecfd30' alt='Inline 2' width='538' height='404'></td>
   </tr>
</table>"
```

The cid's are known in codebehind. In this case ii_15b761fdbaecfd30 & 15b82060d11f1e16.

How can I search the HTML string for the cid's and replace the whole 
img tag with a text?

cid:ii_15b82060d11f1e16 should be replaced with 'some text 1',
cid:ii_15b761fdbaecfd30 should be replaced with 'some text 1'...

```
string sHTML_Output = "<table>
   <tr>
      <td>some text 1...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>some text 2...</td>
   </tr>
</table>"
```

Thank you

Comment: Consider using the [HTML Agility pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
\<img.*?cid\:(.*?)'.*?\>
```

You can test it [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%3Cimg.*%3Fcid%5C%3A%28.*%3F%29%27.*%3F%5C%3E&i=string%20sHTML%20%3D%20%22%3Ctable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%27cid%3Aii_15b82060d11f1e16%27%20alt%3D%27Inline%201%27%20width%3D%27538%27%20height%3D%27404%27%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%27cid%3Aii_15b761fdbaecfd30%27%20alt%3D%27Inline%202%27%20width%3D%27538%27%20height%3D%27404%27%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%22)

You can also change regex to include specific cid and then replace it with your text